# how to make chrome default applications link handler in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, protocol-handler

Currently, Windows 10 decides to open some links within programs and application by calling Edge and sending some others to IE. I would like to have everything related to internet browsers to be opened in Chrome. I know how to change default programs and associated file types but some are impossible to change and are blacked out/reserved only for IE/Edge. Is that possible to have Chrome as the only browser? Sure I can always copy the address from IE/Edge and reopen it in Chrome but this does not make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Follow `Control Panel - Default Programs - Set Default Programs`. From there you can set Chrome as default for every file extension and protocol it can open.

Comment: Would you please read the question? > I know how to change default programs and associated file types but some are impossible to change and are blacked out/reserved only for IE/Edge.